# MySQL - Copying data from one table to another

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to copy the data from one row and create a new one with some of the values.

I think I have it basically working BUT I want to set value of `meta_key` to additional_articles_0_article_url, and not copy the value "articles"

And after that occurs, create new row, with using the same post_id?

Any ideas?

```
INSERT INTO tpl_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT m.post_id, m.meta_key, m.meta_value
FROM tpl_postmeta m
WHERE m.meta_key = "articles" AND m.meta_value LIKE "%.com%";

INSERT INTO tpl_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) 
VALUES ('same post_id as above','_additional_articles_0_article_title', 'New Article')
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want this:

```
INSERT INTO tpl_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
    SELECT m.post_id, 'additional_articles_0_article_url', m.meta_value
    FROM tpl_postmeta m
    WHERE m.meta_key = "articles" AND m.meta_value LIKE "%.com%";
```

Comment: Just about to hit enter :)

Comment: Thanks, I just added one additional question